# How to configure solr to index and search the Image/Audio/Video files and their contents?

Tags: solr, binaryfiles, apache-tika

Solr Version: 7.6.0

Using TIKA Parsers from basic solr setup provided I was able to upload Image and Video files from Documents tab(My Core) of Solr Admin console using Request-Handler(qt) as "/update/extract/". Now when I query I could only see the metadata of these files like file size, width, height, name details etc., Is there any possibility to parse the content of the image and audio files and retrieve the search results? Do we need to change any configuration settings?

Also will post.jar support to index these kind of data ( Image/Audio/Video )?

Comment: So what do you want this content to be for image, video and audio files?

Comment: Once my image or video files are indexed, while querying I would like to get text information relevant to the query string. Is that feasible? If so, which Tika parsers and configurations we have to use?

Comment: But what is "text information relevant to the query string"? What is "relevant text information" for those kind of files?

Comment: The metadata and any textual data available in the image/video is what you are going to get. I do't think here is any magic that will get  contents from images like AI processing or anything like that,

Comment: @Mats, The 'relevant text information' I was referring to is if the video or image files are containing text information (That matches as that of our query) in their content, then how can we retrieve those results.                   

Thanks for the input s1m3n ! If I need to retrieve the text information content from image/videos how do I need to configure my solr to get the output?

Thank You!

Comment: Finally after a long search, I came across "Tesseract OCR" parser in Tika which would solve the problem of indexing the text information content from image/videos

Comment: I believe there are services that can transcribe audio as text at a passable level of accuracy. This would allow a webinar to be indexed based on what people say.